# Why Visual Studio 2019 for Mac does not show the XAML designer when a XAML file is cliicked?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2019, designer

Why Visual Studio does not show the Designer when I click in a XAML file and instead it shows the GIT panel below the text?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Very good question, google does not show anything. Have come to a solution?

Comment: Not yet! this problem came out of the blue some days ago and I cant fix it.